# Best calculus books for Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, math, books, calculus

Recommend some calculus books for Deep Learning and neural networks. I know what is integration, differentiation, derivates, limits on a based level. I would like to understand on deep level the calculus behind Deep Learning and neural networks.

Comment: Quite a broad question, but I think we should have some sort of community wiki to handle such queries. But check out Ian Goodfellow's book on the same. It is a must read.

Comment: The first chapters of ["Deep learning", by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/), focuses on math, mostly linear algebra and calculus.